# How to keep page design when I print it new tab Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, printing

I use this function to make print

```
     function printContent(el,tble,img) {         
                var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML
                   +" <div class='row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks'></span><b></b></div>"
                   + document.getElementById(tble).innerHTML
                   + document.getElementById(img).innerHTML;

                var w = window.open();   
               $(w.document.body).html(printcontent);
                w.print();
}
```

this works fine for me but the problem is it didn't contain the same page design and the print page has no design

please help

Comment: I guess you mean all your CSS etc is lost? How about write it to a container element instead of writing it to your body? $('#container').html(printcontent); or am I not understanding you correctly?

Comment: @Seph yes, it true but how can I include them again in print page?

Comment: I take it you don't have a link to a print stylesheet? In that case see Rodrigo's answer.

Comment: @Seph Sorry I can't understand it clearly , I have no new page it just this function ,where shall I call the css links in this function which create new tab

Answer (score 0):

You should use a link in the head of your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="style.css">
```

Note the media attribute.

Edit:

```
var bodyContent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML
                   +" <div class='row'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-tasks'></span><b></b></div>"
                   + document.getElementById(tble).innerHTML
                   + document.getElementById(img).innerHTML;

var windowHTML = '<html><head><title>Print page</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="style.css"></head><body>' + bodyContent + '</body>';

var w = window.open();   
w.document.write(windowHTML);
w.print();
```

Comment: I have many of js files and many of css files in my page which calls this function to open new tab to print the content where shall I link all my css or js files ?

Comment: I edited my post with an example. Look that I'm writing the whole HTML page and adding the link tag inside the head, as you probably have in your HTML today.

Comment: nothing changed also when I inspect element to the new page the head seems like empty

Comment: The title isn't being shown too? Did you use the same code as above?

Comment: Yes but I changed the css link to my own